# Inputs on correct usage of binding:"required" in Golang struct

Tags: go

I have a struct (with 1 field, for simplification purpose here) for which data comes from another function.

Further, for the struct field, I have put **binding:"required"**, as I need it to be non-empty/present.

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Config struct {
    Name       string   `yaml:"name"    json:"name"     binding:"required"`
} 

func main() {
    var myConfig Config

    var rawConfig = []byte(`{}`)  // Empty, Nothing getting passed.

    err := json.Unmarshal(rawConfig, &myConfig)
        if err != nil {
          panic(err)
        }
    fmt.Printf("Name = %s\n", myConfig.Name)
}
```

When I run this, even if Name value has not been passed in, it passes.

**Output:**

```
Name =
```

Go playground Code link : https://play.golang.org/p/zA6nij9vTvY

I want to achieve the following:

- As I expect the 'Name' field to be present, what do I do to make it fail, if not present. Is unmarshalling not expected to use binding=required tag and fail ?
- Else, whats the best approach to figure out if a required field is not present so that we fail ?
- Or is the crude way of iterating on fields, and figuring out if empty, the only way ?

Comment: Standard json unmarshaler does not recognize the `binding:required` tag. You have to check if required fields are empty.

Answer (score 0):

You might do this in hard way by iterating over struct fields using reflect, get the tags and parse them which is not advised unless you need some customizations.

Or you might like use available validator packages:
https://github.com/dealancer/validate

```
    package main

    import (
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
        "gopkg.in/dealancer/validate.v2"
    )

    type Config struct {
        Name       string   `yaml:"name"    json:"name"     validate:"empty=false"`
    }

    func main() {
        var myConfig Config

        var rawConfig = []byte(`{}`)  // Empty, Nothing getting passed.

        err := json.Unmarshal(rawConfig, &myConfig)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        err = validate.Validate(myConfig)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Name = %s\n", myConfig.Name)
    }
```